# Add newline before and after if,for,while statements using clang-format (Astyle equivalent --break-blocks)

Tags: c++, c, llvm, clang-format

I have been using the `clang-format` style available in the Linux Kernel repository and I would like to tweak it to my own needs. I was trying to add a newline before and after if,for and while blocks.

Although I have never used Astyle, it achieves the desired behavior with the `--break-blocks` [flag](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/astyle.html#_Padding_Options)

An example from Astyle's documentation

```
isFoo = true;
if (isFoo) {
    bar();
} else {
    anotherBar();
}
isBar = false;
```

becomes:

```
isFoo = true;

if (isFoo) {
    bar();
} else {
    anotherBar();
}

isBar = false;
```

I have searched the documentation of `clang-format` but I could not find a flag that could achieve the same style.

Is there a way to achieve this style using `clang-format`?